# I need to add animation to flutter splash screen. Is it possible to add animated launch screen?

Tags: android, flutter, android-vectordrawable

I need to add animation to flutter splash screen. I have modified launch_background.xml  to add icon.

launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        />

<!--    &lt;!&ndash; You can insert your own image assets here &ndash;&gt;-->
    <item
        android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_small" />
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

Comment: Yes. It is indeed possible.

Comment: sorry, it is not possible - static content only

Comment: @NisanthReddy can you tell me how it is possible?

Comment: @AmarMaharjan I suggest you give this a try once. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen. If you have never created `animations` in android using xml, I would suggest following a tutorial first. There are many on youtube and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible by using `animated_splash_screen`.
you can find it on pub.dev here
https://pub.dev/packages/animated_splash_screen/install

This is demo example from  the readme of package.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSplashScreen(
      splash: 'images/splash.png',
      nextScreen: MainScreen(),
      splashTransition: SplashTransition.rotationTransition,
      pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.scale,
    );
  }
```

All the examples are given in description of package. The parameter `nextScreen` specifies your first screen that you want to launch on app opening after ending of the splash screen.

Comment: This splash screen is displayed after the initial splash screen I wanted to implement animation on the initial splash screen

Comment: This is because you have specified your splash screen inside the xml in android files. This package works without making any changes in xml. you can directly add animation inside this class and it will automatically do the configuration for you

Comment: @AmarMaharjan you can only have static initial splash screen, no animations